# How to do Leg Grab in Mortal Kombat 4?

Tags: mortal-kombat-4

Sonya's Leg Grab is D + LP + BL, where + means, I suppose, to press/hold simultaneously. This is the only regular move that's marked with a plus and I cannot perform - I've tried a number of keying techniques. How do you press it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't press them all simultaneously at once, you gotta hold down and block, then press low punch.

So it's more like: `Hold D + BLK, LP`